# Date picker popup window

Tags: css, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I need an advice with the styling of date picker module in Java FX with an assistance of CSS classes.

It is specifically the popup window in which I used also the scenic view to look up the CSS code. But doesn't work in the popup window. I need a help how to style popup in the calendar view.

(using intelijIdea)

This is my code and the attached picture.

[image]

```
.date-picker .combo-box {
-fx-background-insets:0px ;
-fx-border-width: 0px;
  }

.date-picker .text-field{
-fx-background-radius:0px ;
-fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.date-picker .arrow-button{
-fx-background-radius:0px ;
-fx-background-color: #232323;
}

.date-picker .arrow-button .arrow{
-fx-background-radius:0px ;
-fx-background-color: #1783CC;
}

.date-picker .arrow-button:hover .arrow{
-fx-background-radius:0px ;
-fx-background-color: #40a9ef;
 }

 .date-picker .button {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-border-color:transparent;
-fx-pref-height: 35px;
-fx-pref-width: 35px;
 }

 .date-picker .button:hover {
-fx-border-color:transparent;
-fx-pref-height: 35px;
-fx-pref-width: 35px;
 }

.date-picker .button .arrow:pressed {
-fx-border-color:transparent;
-fx-pref-height: 35px;
-fx-pref-width: 35px;
 }

 .date-picker .cell {
-fx-background-color: #232323;
-fx-pref-width:20px ;
-fx-pref-height:25px ;
 }

.date-picker .cell:hover {
-fx-background-color: #1783CC;
-fx-pref-width:20px ;
-fx-pref-height:25px ;
}

.date-picker .cell:focused {
-fx-background-color:#11659e;
-fx-pref-width:20px ;
-fx-pref-height:25px ;
 }

.date-picker-popup  {
-fx-border-color: #1783CC;
-fx-background-color: black;
 }
```

Comment: You say that you want to style the popup calendar but you do not state what exactly do you want to achieve. Can you be more specific on the requirement?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i want to style all components in popup window of date picker. I looking for styleClass of buttonbar popup date picker, class of month cells, year cells, day cells, week cells, background .. and pseudo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most style classes of the DatePicker popup can be found in the `DatePickerContent.java` or in one of the JavaFX's theme stylesheet. 
For instance, if you're using the modena theme then you will find the these styleclasses in [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#l2934) (from line 2934)

A quick workaround when using ScenicView would be to prevent the popup from being closed:

```
    datePicker.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            datePicker.show();
        }
    });
```